# Pandas: How to perform the same calculation on multiple columns, which come from a passed-in list?

Tags: pandas

Given the following code, I'd like to calculate three additional columns called "Expected Sales {letter}" that multiplies each column of A, B, and C by the Price column. But to do this, I would like to pass in a list of column names such that only those with 'Group' in the column name get multiplied (meaning that Other does nothing)

```
data = [(3,5,7), (2,4,6), (5,8,9.2)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Group A','Group B','Group C'])
df['Fruit'] = ('apples', 'bananas', 'pears')
df['Price'] = (1, 0.5, 2)
df['Other'] = ("blah1", "blah2", "blah3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` to select your columns then use `rename` to replace "Group" string by "Expected Sales":

```
df1 = (df.filter(like='Group').mul(df['Price'], axis=0)
         .rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('Group', 'Expected Sales')))
out = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> out

   Group A  Group B  Group C    Fruit  Price  Other  Expected Sales A  Expected Sales B  Expected Sales C
0        3        5      7.0   apples    1.0  blah1               3.0               5.0               7.0
1        2        4      6.0  bananas    0.5  blah2               1.0               2.0               3.0
2        5        8      9.2    pears    2.0  blah3              10.0              16.0              18.4
```